# bundler update fails with mysterious permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler

I can't tell why bundler is looking for actionpack-1.4.0.gem, but it is causing my bundle update command to die.

Here are all the relevant transcripts (to the best of my knowledge...)

```
$ bundle update
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Using rake (0.8.7) 
Using Ascii85 (1.0.0) 
/opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:145:in `initialize': Permission denied - /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/cache/actionpack-1.4.0.gem (Errno::EACCES)
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:145:in `open'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:145:in `download'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/source.rb:255:in `download_gem_from_uri'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/source.rb:72:in `fetch'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:45:in `run'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in `each'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in `run'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/cli.rb:275:in `update'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `send'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.10/bin/bundle:13
from /opt/local/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
from /opt/local/bin/bundle:19
```

OK, so it's failing due to a permission denied on this path, but there's no file there:

```
/mydev/ElectionManager(export-work)> ls /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/cache/actionpack-1.4.0.gem
ls: /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/cache/actionpack-1.4.0.gem: No such file or directory
```

Ok, let's look at the environment. Is there something fishy there?

```
/mydev/ElectionManager(export-work)> env
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
GEM_HOME=/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
TERM=xterm-color
SHELL=/bin/bash
TMPDIR=/var/folders/BF/BFIqAzICGVuMEvQQwzRkvE+++TI/-Tmp-/
Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render=/tmp/launch-9H2vLV/Render
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=273.1
USER=pitosalas
COMMAND_MODE=unix2003
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/launch-4WmMHp/Listeners
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0:0
 PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin/
PWD=/mydev/ElectionManager
EDITOR=mate -w
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
PS1=\w$(__git_ps1 "(%s)")> 
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users/pitosalas
LOGNAME=pitosalas
DISPLAY=/tmp/launch-p24Csr/org.x:0
OLDPWD=/Users/pitosalas
_=/usr/bin/env
```

Nothing fishy. Let's look through all the code to see if actionpack-1 is ever even mentioned:

```
/mydev/ElectionManager(export-work)> grep  -r -i "actionpack-1" .
/mydev/ElectionManager(export-work)>
```

Nope it's not mentioned. And what is in Gemfile?

```
$ cat Gemfile 


source :gemcutter

#gem 'rails', "2.3.8"
gem 'rails'
gem "sqlite3-ruby", "1.2.5", :require => "sqlite3"

gem "authlogic"
gem "prawn", '>= 0.7.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 2.3.11'
gem 'tpitale-constant_cache', '>= 0.1.2', :require => 'constant_cache'
 gem 'rubyzip', '>= 0.9.4', :require => 'zip/zip'
 gem 'redgreen', '>=1.2.2'
 gem 'searchlogic', '>=2.4.14'
 gem 'cancan'
 gem 'fastercsv'

 group :development do
 end

 group :test do
   gem 'thoughtbot-shoulda', '>=2.10.2',  :require => 'shoulda'
   gem 'machinist'
   gem 'faker'
   gem 'mocha'
   gem 'pdf-reader'
   gem 'awesome_print'
   gem 'turn'
   gem 'rspec'
 end

 group 'cucumber' do
   gem 'machinist'
   gem 'faker'
   gem 'cucumber-rails',  '>=0.3.0',  :require => false
   gem 'database_cleaner',  '>=0.5.0', :require => false
 gem 'webrat',  '>=0.7.0', :require => false
 gem 'pickle', :require => false
end

group :production do

end
```

Ok that looks pretty good. What does gem think it knows about rails gems?

```
/mydev/ElectionManager(export-work)> gem list rails
```

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

```
rails (3.0.4, 2.3.8, 2.3.5, 2.3.4, 2.2.2)
rails_best_practices (0.6.4, 0.3.26, 0.3.19, 0.3.16)
/mydev/ElectionManager(export-work)>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionPack is a dependency of rails. What happens when you run a `bundle install`? That should install the relevant `actionpack` version.

However, It does seem like it's looking for an old version of `actionpack` though.

Search for `actionpack` in your `Gemfile.lock`. That will tell you what it's a dependency of.

Also if bundler is trying to install to system gems, you may need to `sudo bundle install` although you're better off giving it a path to install to:

`bundle install --path=/something/specific/to/this/project`

Comment: I deleted my Gemfile.lock before trying this...The instructions for bundle warn strenuously against sudoing ...

Comment: The instructions for bundle warn strenuously against sudoing so I am not sure about that. The question is, why oh why is bundler looking for actionpack-1.x. I see nothing referencing it.

Comment: That's why I suggested providing a specific path to bundler, if you were having permissions issues. Do you have a `./bundle/config` file? What are its contents? Also have you tried `bundle install` instead of `bundle update`

Comment: I have tried bundle install as well as update; I don't have a ./bundle/config nor a ~/.bundle/config file.

Comment: I suspect that my problem has to do with the fact that I am using macports, which stores gem under /opt/local/bin/gem - but that my Mac OS X comes with a base gem executable under /usr/bin/gem. Somehow bundler is getting mixed up but I can't tell how. .... Moreover, I fully uninstalled macports's version of gem, and fully reinstalled it, and that still didn't solve it.

Comment: Did you try giving bundler a path? `bundle install --path=/wherever` We often use `--path=./gem` so the gems remain with the project. Bundler *shouldn't* look anywhere else for gems.

Answer (score 1):

Did you originally install rails using `sudo gem install ...`? When bundle runs without sudo privileges it won't be able to update these. Delete the originally installed gem and rerun bundler.

Comment: Yes I did do use sudo gem install originally. I will try what you say, that seems like a safe thing to do.

Comment: I tried uninstalling rails: "$ sudo gem uninstall rails", but I still get the same error: "$ bundle update" gives me "/opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb:145:in `initialize': Permission denied - /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/cache/actionpack-1.4.0.gem (Errno::EACCES)
"

Comment: You would have to uninstall actionpack too, and probably other dependencies.